# Is there a statistical mechanical model with the same qualitative behaviour as polarity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, models

Every chef and chemist knows that oil and water do not mix and that this is due to the polar nature of the water molecule and the non-polar nature of the oil molecule. In fact if one starts the oil in small drops they assemble into larger drops. Is there a natural statistical mechanical model which  has similar predictions? I.e. some number preserving evolution of cells on a grid that exhibit clustering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One model in which such a behavior can be described precisely is the Ising model.

This can be done in any dimension, but the results are easier to state (and more precise) in the two-dimensional case, so I'll stick to that.

Consider an Ising model in a finite domain in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, say $V_L = \{1,\dots,L\}^2$ with $+$ boundary condition, below the critical temperature $T_c$. Denotes by $m^*(T)>0$ be the spontaneous magnetization.

Let us fix $m\in (-m^*(T),m^*(T))$ and consider the conditional probability measure
$$
\mu^+_{T,L} \Bigl(\cdot \Bigm| \sum_{i\in V_L} \sigma_i = m |V_L|\Bigr),
$$
where $\mu^+_{T,L}$ is the Gibbs measure for the Ising model in $V_L$ at temperature $T$ and with $+$ boundary condition and $|V_L| = L^2$ is the area of $V_L$. I have assumed that $m$ has been chosen such that $m|V_L|$ is a possible value for the magnetization in $V_L$. Note that this conditional probability measure corresponds precisely to the canonical ensemble in the lattice gas language (that is, if we identify $-$ spins with particles and $+$ spins with vacancies, then the measure above is the canonical Gibbs measure with total number of particles given by $\tfrac12(1-m)|V_L|$).

One can then prove that, with probability going to $1$ as $L\to\infty$, configurations sampled from the above measure will have the following structure:

- There is exactly one droplet of $-$ phase of diameter of order $L$, immersed inside the $+$ phase;
- Once rescaled by $1/L$, the shape of this droplet converges to a deterministic shape, given by the solution of the following variational problem: minimize the surface tension among all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with area $\frac{m^*-m}{2m^*(T)}$. The minimizing shape is known as the **Wulff shape**.
- All other droplets are microscopic (of diameter at most $\log L$).

Since a picture is worth a thousand words, here is a typical configuration with $L=998$ and $m=0$; black pixels correspond to $-$ spins (particles), white pixels to $+$ spins (vacancies):

[image]

The restriction to $+$ boundary condition is not a requirement. But considering more general boundary conditions (or even boundary fields) leads to additional interesting phenomena (for instance, the droplet might attach to the boundary, a manifestation of the wetting transition in the Ising model).

If you want additional information on the above, I suggest that you read Section 4.12.1 in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), or [this review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911106) (more technical, but much more detailed).

Comment: Cool! Can I still do some form of Glauber dynamics to approach the Gibbs measure starting from some arbitrary state?

Comment: You need to preserve the magnetization, so you must use Kawasaki dynamics, but yes, this will converge to the state I describe (it's actually the way the simulation above was obtained).